# Positioning nodes in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to construct a bordered 4 x 2 array of numbers in Tikz using the following code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\octada}[8]{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,1.05) -- (1.6,1.05) -- (1.6,-1.05) -- (0,-1.05) -- (0,1.05);
\draw (0.4,0.75) node {$#1$};
\draw (1.2,0.75) node {$#5$};
\draw (0.4,0.25) node {$#2$};
\draw (1.2,0.25) node {$#6$};
\draw (0.4,-0.25) node {$#3$};
\draw (1.2,-0.25) node {$#7$};
\draw (0.4,-0.75) node {$#4$};
\draw (1.2,-0.75) node {$#8$};
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
\octada{1}{1}{2}{2}{-1}{-1}{2}{2}
\end{document}
```

This produce a 4 x 2 array in which the entries are centrally aligned within their columns.

Is it possible to modify my code so that the numbers in each column are all right aligned with one another (i.e. so that the minus signs do not affect the alignment of the numbers)?

Comment: Add `[anchor=east]` in the ones you want aligned. Maybe the `\matrix` macro would also help you writing this more concisely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess `anchor=east` is what you are after here:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\octada}[8]{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,1.05) -- (1.6,1.05) -- (1.6,-1.05) -- (0,-1.05) -- (0,1.05);
\draw (0.4,0.75) node {$#1$};
\draw[anchor=east] (1.2,0.75) node {$#5$};
\draw (0.4,0.25) node {$#2$};
\draw[anchor=east] (1.2,0.25) node {$#6$};
\draw (0.4,-0.25) node {$#3$};
\draw[anchor=east] (1.2,-0.25) node {$#7$};
\draw (0.4,-0.75) node {$#4$};
\draw[anchor=east] (1.2,-0.75) node {$#8$};
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
\octada{1}{1}{2}{2}{-1}{-1}{2}{2}
\end{document}
```

You may want finer control over the alignment and width of the text in the nodes, for that there are the keys described in section "17.4.3
Text Parameters: Alignment and Width for Multi-Line Text" of the pgf manual.

Also, you may consider using `\matrix` instead of manual positioning.
It is described in section "20.2
Matrices are Nodes" of the pgf manual.